# class 'int' instead of type 'int': string indices must be integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, integer

I have a simple Python function where I'm swapping values in a string.  I'm doing this by generating a pseudorandom integer, then swapping it with the next index or previous index to avoid out of bounds exceptions.

However, I am getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.  When I add a print statement to check the type of the index that is generated by the `secrets.randbelow()` function, it returns `class 'int'`, whereas I would expect `type 'int'`.  Is this what's causing the error?

**Function**

```
import secrets as random


def shuffle_sequence(sequence):
    sequence_len = int(len(sequence))
    for x in range(0, sequence_len):
        swap_index = random.randbelow(sequence_len)
        next_index = 0
        if swap_index != sequence_len:
            next_index = swap_index + 1
        else:
            next_index = swap_index - 1
        sequence[swap_index, next_index] = sequence[next_index, swap_index]
        x += 1
    return sequence
```

I even adding an int conversion to the first line of the function hoping that would help, but it's returning the same class of `int`, which is expected.

To clarify, `sequence` is a string of letters, numbers, and symbols.

Comment: Python 2 called it a `type`, Python 3 unified it to `class`. You will never see `<type 'int'>` in Python 3.

Comment: You are trying to index `sequence` with a tuple.

Comment: Also, strings are immutable; you can't assign to a particular position within an existing string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a tuple to index a list. Use two separate indexing operations to swap two indices:

```
sequence[swap_index], sequence[next_index] = sequence[next_index], sequence[swap_index]
```

Note that your test `swap_index != sequence_len` will never be true, because `secrets.randbelow()` already guarantees that you get a value between 0 and *below* the argument value. You will run into an index error when `swap_index` is equal to `sequence_len - 1`, because `next_index` is then set to be equal to `sequence_len`, which is not a valid index.

Next, if `sequence` is an immutable type, such as a string, then assigning to indices can't work. You'll have to convert your string to a mutable sequence first, like a list, the convert back to a string afterwards (using `str.join()`).

And finally, your implementation only swaps directly consecutive elements, which is not really a proper shuffle. You need to consider all elements not yet swapped instead.

And finally, to shuffle a sequence 'securely', just use the `secrets.SystemRandom()` class and call it's [`shuffle()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
from secrets import SystemRandom

sysrandom = SystemRandom()

def shuffle_sequence(sequence):
    sequence = list(sequence)
    sysrandom.shuffle(sequence)
    return ''.join(sequence)
```

The [implementation for `Random.shuffle()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/random.py#L274-L278) goes over the indices of the sequence *in reverse* and picks out a random element that lies before the iteration index:

```
for next_index in reversed(range(1, sequence_len)):
    swap_index = random.randbelow(next_index)
    sequence[swap_index], sequence[next_index] = sequence[next_index], sequence[swap_index]
```

Comment: I'm new to Python and have been working out how things work, been out of the development world for a while.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

1. You are trying to index a string with a tuple, not an integer.
2. Strings are immutable, so you can't swap two characters in an existing string.

You need to expand the string to a list, perform your swaps there, then join the list elements back into a string.

```
def shuffle_sequence(sequence):
    # "abc" -> ["a", "b", "c"]
    elements = list(sequence)

    sequence_len = int(len(sequence))
    for x in range(0, sequence_len):
        swap_index = random.randbelow(sequence_len)
        next_index = 0
        if swap_index != sequence_len:
            next_index = swap_index + 1
        else:
            next_index = swap_index - 1

        # Swap elements of the list
        elements[swap_index], elements[next_index] = elements[next_index], elements[swap_index]
        x += 1

    # Combine the elements into a single string
    return ''.join(elements)
```

Comment: This still has a non-zero chance to throw an `IndexError`, and it only swaps *consecutive elements*.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even try to address any errors in the algorithm, just the obvious mechanical errors.